# python: how to redirect from desktop app to url, wait user to accept the authorization and get authorization code

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, spotify

I'm working on an app using the Spotify API but I'm a bit new to all of this. I'm trying to get the Authorization Code with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)
My problem is how do I redirect the user to the `query` where he has to ACCEPT the authorization and make my app to wait until the user clicks on ACCEPT. When he does this, the user will be redirected and that new URL (as the docs said) will contain the authorization code that I need to then exchange it for an authorization token.

This is my function so far to get that authorization code:

```py
def get_auth_code(self):
    code_challenge = self.get_code_challenge_PKCE()
    scopes_needed = "user-read-email%20user-read-private%20playlist-read-collaborative%20playlist-modify-public%20playlist-read-private%20playlist-modify-private%20user-library-modify%20user-library-read"

    endpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    query = f"{endpoint}?client_id={self.client_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={self.redirect_uri}&scope={scopes_needed}&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge={code_challenge}"
    webbrowser.open(query)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Set up a web server.

To programmatially extract the access tokens you need a web server to handle the redirection after the user logs in on Spotify (which you redirected them to). Now this server *can* be the user pasting the URI to an input field on a terminal, but obviously this isn't ideal for user experience. It leaves room for lots of mistakes.

I've authored a Spotify Web API client, whose internals might be useful for you to examine. [For example](https://tekore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/auth_server.html), you can use Flask to construct the server. The main principle is using one endpoint (i.e. `/login`) to redirect (code `307` worked for me browsers won't remember it) the user to a callback (i.e. `/callback`) which recieves the `code` parameter with which you can request an access token.

OAuth2 can be a bit of a pain to implement locally, I know. In my library I also made a [similar function](https://github.com/felix-hilden/tekore/blob/master/tekore/_auth/util.py#L55) that you are constructing using `webbrowser`, but it does have the manual copy-pasting quirk. To use functions you can define yourself for brevity, the gist of it is:

```
verifier = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)  # for PKCE, not in my library yet
url = user_authorisation_url(scope, state, verifier)

# Communicate with the user
print('Opening browser for Spotify login...')
webbrowser.open(url)
redirected = input('Please paste redirect URL: ').strip()

code = parse_code_from_url(redirected)
state_back = parse_state_from_url(redirected)
assert state == state_back  # For that added security juice
token = request_user_token(code, verifier)
```

Comment: Yes, I did It similar, but at the end I decided to seach a little more and create a basic server so I can get the response and it works "kindda" fine. Still working on some improvements